# PHP str_replace any number pattern

Tags: php, str-replace

I have what seems like quite a simple query.
I have the following code in PHP:

```
$newThumb = str_replace('style="width:170px;"','',$nolinkThumb);
```

The problem that I have is that the number '170' can be any number therefore I would like my str_replace to reflect this. I have tried using:

```
$newThumb = str_replace('style="width:[0-9]px;"','',$nolinkThumb);
```

But this doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use regex, but `[0-9]` in regex means "the digits 0 to 9 repeated once".

What you're actually searching for is `[0-9]+` which means "the digits 0 to 9 repeated one or more times":

```
$string = preg_replace('/style="width:[0-9]+px;"/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `str_replace` you need to use `preg_replace` to support regular expressions. More info can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

So, for example, you could use:

`$newThumb = preg_replace('/style="width:[0-9]+px;"/', '', $nolinkThumb);`

Nevertheless, you should probably look at generating your HTML correctly, so that the style is kept separately (for example, in a CSS file) from the content and the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newThumb = preg_replace('/style="width:[0-9]{1,}px;/', '', $nolinkThumb);
```

this regex also work. matching 1-X digits and replace the whole string

hope it helps